# What is the difference between XMLHttpRequest and Service Worker API to preload assets of my web application

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, service-worker

I have the code below to preload specific files into the cache and it works fine using `XMLHttpRequest`.

The question is what is the difference between my approach and using the **Service Worker API** if I only want to use it on Chrome.

What are the pros and cons of Service Worker API compare to using `XMLHttpRequest`?

If they both save data to **browser's cache** why I should use Service Worker?

```js
preload();

function preload(){

(function (global, factory) {
 typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
 typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
 (global.Preload = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

 function preloadOne(url, done) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onprogress = event => {
   if (!event.lengthComputable) return false
   let item = this.getItemByUrl(event.target.responseURL);
   item.completion = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
   item.downloaded = event.loaded;
   item.total = event.total;
   this.updateProgressBar(item);
  };
  xhr.onload = event => {
   let type = event.target.response.type;
   let blob = new Blob([event.target.response], { type: type });
   let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   let responseURL = event.target.responseURL;
   let item = this.getItemByUrl(responseURL);
   item.blobUrl = url;
   item.fileName = responseURL.substring(responseURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   item.type = type;
   item.size = blob.size;
   done(item);
  };
  
  xhr.onerror = event => {
        console.log('Error has happend so we restart the preloading..');
        preload();
        };
        
  xhr.send();
 }

 function updateProgressBar(item) {
  var sumCompletion = 0;
  var maxCompletion = this.status.length * 100;

  for (var itemStatus of this.status) {
   if (itemStatus.completion) {
    sumCompletion += itemStatus.completion;
   }
  }
  var totalCompletion = parseInt((sumCompletion / maxCompletion) * 100);

  if (!isNaN(totalCompletion)) {
   this.onprogress({
    progress: totalCompletion,
    item: item
   });
  }
 }

 function getItemByUrl(rawUrl) {
     for (var item of this.status) {
         if (item.url == rawUrl) return item
     }
 }

 function fetch(list) { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.loaded = list.length;
   for (let item of list) {
    this.status.push({ url: item });
    this.preloadOne(item, item => {
     this.onfetched(item);
     this.loaded--;
     if (this.loaded == 0) {
      this.oncomplete(this.status);
      resolve(this.status);
     }
    });
   }
  })
 }

 function Preload() {
  return {
   status: [],
   loaded: false,
   onprogress: () => {},
   oncomplete: () => {},
   onfetched: () => {},
   fetch,
   updateProgressBar,
   preloadOne,
   getItemByUrl
  }
 }

 return Preload;

})));


 const preload = Preload();

 preload.fetch([
     'https://round-arm-authority.000webhostapp.com/Ultimate%20Video%20Hack/videos/vid1.mp4'

 ]).then(items => {
   // use either a promise or 'oncomplete'
   console.log(items);
 });

 preload.oncomplete = items => {
   console.log(items);
 }

 preload.onprogress = event => {
   console.log(event.progress + '%');
 }

 preload.onfetched = item => {
   console.log(item);
 }
 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A service worker allows you to intercept [navigation requests](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/high-performance-loading) and serve HTML directly from the cache, while still having an out-of-band mechanism for updating that HTML as you deploy changes to your site.

A service worker allows you to use more complex [update and fallback strategies](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook) for your subresources than the HTTP cache allows.

Comment: How does Service Worker determine that a specific file like an mp4 video or a js file has been updated since the last time it has been cached?

Comment: It doesn't, in and of itself. But you can add in some logic to do that, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925707/using-service-workers-to-both-use-cache-and-update-in-background/60954330#60954330